# The Weather Section in XBMC

Tags: xbmc

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and XBMC 12.1 - a fantastic product by the way. In the Weather Section, I would like for it to display the temperature in Celsius, not Fahrenheit. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

System > Settings > Appearance > International

Set your time zone and time zone country to the right settings.